# Python function that gives a maximum of 1.2

Tags: python, function

I have this code here:

```
def maximum():
    i = int(float(input("What is the maximum value?")))
    if i < 1.2:
        return print("ERROR: Maximum should be greater than 1.2"), maximum()
    else:
        return i
maximum()
```

But it doesn't let me use numbers between 0-1.9 showing an output of

```
What is the maximum value?1.2
ERROR: Maximum should be greater than 1.2
```

What should I change in the function to allow decimals to be accepted?

Comment: Because you are using `int`. Look what happens at `int(1.9)`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesn't let me use numbers between 0-1.9"?

Comment: I'm also pretty sure your failure case isn't doing what you expect. You're calling `print` and then recursively calling `maximum`, combining the results into a tuple. So if the user answers incorrectly a few times, the final result isn't going to be `1.3`; it's going to be `(None, (None, (None, (None, 1.3))))`.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the offending values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the conversion to an `int`, as this will floor your `float`.

```
def maximum():
    i = float(input("What is the maximum value?"))
    if i < 1.2:
        return print("ERROR: Maximum should be greater than 1.2"), maximum()
    else:
        return i
maximum()
```

Answer (score 1):

`int` means integer, i.e. a whole number. When you call `int`, you're truncating (rounding down) to the nearest whole number, so any numbers from `1.0` to `1.9` just get truncated to `1`, which is less than `1.2`. You don't need the `int` call if you want a fractional number.

```
i = float(input("What is the maximum value?"))
```